# React stateless functional components and component lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, es6-class

So I just switched to using *stateless functional components* in **React** with **Redux** and I was curious about component lifecycle. Initially I had this :

```
// actions.js

export function fetchUser() {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED',
        payload: {
            name: 'username',
            career: 'Programmer'
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the component I used a componentDidMount to fetch the data like so :

```
// component.js

...
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchUser()
}
...
```

After switching to stateless functional components I now have a container with :

```
// statelessComponentContainer.js

...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: fetchUser().payload
  }
}
...
```

As you can see, currently I am not fetching any data asynchronously. So my question is will this approach cause problems when I start fetching data asynchronously? And also is there a better approach?

I checked out this [blog](http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-react-createclass-es6-classes-or-stateless-functional-components/), where they say **If your components need lifecycle methods, use ES6 classes**.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't do what you are trying to to do in `mapStateToProps`.  Redux follows a [unidirectional data flow](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html) pattern, where by component dispatch action, which update state, which changes component.  You should not expect your action to return the data, but rather expect the store to update with new data.

Following this approach, especially once you are fetching the data asynchronously, means you will have to cater for a state where your data has not loaded yet.  There are plenty of questions and tutorials out there for that (even in another answer in this question), so I won't worry to put an example in here for you.

Secondly, wanting to fetch data asynchronously when a component mounts is a common use case.  Wanting to write nice functional component is a common desire.  Luckily, I have a library that allows you to do both: [react-redux-lifecycle](https://github.com/mpeyper/react-redux-lifecycle).

Now you can write:

```
import { onComponentDidMount } from 'react-redux-lifecycle'
import { fetchUser } from './actions'

const User = ({ user }) => {
   return // ...
}

cont mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user = state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(onComponentDidMount(fetchUser)(User))
```

I have made a few assumptions about your component names and store structure, but I hope it is enough to get the idea across.  I'm happy to clarify anything for you.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of react-redux-lifecycle library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't render any view if there is no data yet. Here is how you do this.

Approach of solving your problem is to return a `promise` from `this.props.fetchUser()`. You need to `dispatch` your action using [react-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) *(See examples and information how to setup. It is easy!)*.

Your `fetchUser` action should look like this:

```
export function fetchUser() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(dispatch({         
          type: 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED',
          payload: {
            name: 'username',
            career: 'Programmer'
          }
        }))
      });
  };
}
```

Then in your `Component` add to lifecycle method `componentWillMount()` following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchUser()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    })
}
```

Of course your class `constructor` should have initial state `isLoading` set to `true`.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // ...

  this.state({
    isLoading: true
  })
}
```

Finally in your `render()` method add a condition. If your request is not yet completed and we don't have data, print 'data is still loading...' otherwise show `<UserProfile />` Component.

```
render() {
  const { isLoading } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>{ !isLoading ? <UserProfile /> : 'data is still loading...' }</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But does this also mean that I should revert back to es6 classes?

Comment: Yes, more complex logic like this require to use `ES6` classes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: If I helped you mark my answer as answered. Also I have updated `fetchUser` action.